# How to write a MySQL Insert Into Statement with Inner Join?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, inner-join, sql-insert

The user adds information here: [the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DlPI.png)

The information gets added to the shoes table.

The database: [the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbDUX.png)

I want to insert ShoeImage, ShoeName, ShoeStyle, ShoeColor, ShoePrice, and ShoeDescr, and NOT ShoeID (which is autoincrement),ShoeBrandID, and ShoeSizeID.

My insert statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tblShoes VALUES (NULL, '$ShoeImage', '$ShoeName', '$ShoeStyle', '$ShoeColor',
                        '$ShoePrice', '$ShoeDescr')";
```

How to write this insert statement with inner join?

Comment: you need column names, check this for an example: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

**Might works.**

```
INSERT INTO shoes
(
'ShoeImage',
'ShoeName',
'ShoeStyle',
'ShoeColor',
'ShoePrice',
'ShoeDescr',
'ShoeBrandID',
'ShoeSizeID'
)
VALUES(
NULL,
'$ShoeImage',
'$ShoeName',
'$ShoeStyle',
'$ShoeColor',
'$ShoePrice',
'$ShoeDescr',
(SELECT BrandID FROM shoebrand WHERE BrandName = '$ShoeBrand'),
(SELECT SizeID FROM shoesize WHERE Size = '$ShoeSize')
)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are poor. So is cryptic prose. Explain how/why code answers a question. [answer] [Help] PS Please don't [delete & repost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74634917/3404097), edit your post per feedback. PS [mre]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).